# Здравствуйте, помогите решить проблему

Tags: acf

Подскажите, у меня 4 блока в каждом втором блоке  есть дополнительный класс, как мне сделать чтоб когда я создаю через повторитель блоки к каждому второму применялся дополнительный класс ?

Comment: Используйте счетчик в цикле или `get_row_index()` если выводите через `while` и `have_rows()` и деление по модулю